# php $count - Undefined variable:

Tags: php

I have this code that I want to insert a div clear class the it reaches the 5th column:

```
<div class="grid<?php $count++; if ($count == 5) ?>">  
<?php if ($count == 5) { $count = 0; echo '<div class="clearit"></div>'; } ?>
```

It works but I am getting this error that I want to get rid of:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: count  in....template/catalog/product/layout.phtml on line 40
```

where line 40 is `<div class="grid<?php $count++; if ($count == 5) ?>">`

I can't tell where has gone wrong with my limited PHP knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have not declared your variable. If you add `$count = 0;` to the top of your PHP file the error will go away as you have declared the variable.

You should also note that this has nothing to do with Zend Framework.

Comment: You can also surpress these little non-important errors by setting `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`. Ofcourse, it's better to fix them as they're easy to fix but if you don't want to you can hide them.

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it–I'm slowly learning PHP therefore it helps if I know what causes an error and how to go about fixing it. I mentioned zend framework because I'm working from a system built by it and thought maybe it's particular about variables :)

Answer (score -2):

It is better to do that with CSS and not with markup or server side scripting. Let me give you an example:

```
.grid:nth-child(5n+5), .grid.fifth-child { clear: both; }
```

It's not supported in every browser so you can use jQuery to fix that:

```
$('.grid:nth-child(5n+5)').addClass('fifth-child');
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this is not an answer to user's question, I'm not sure that adding javascript and non-standard CSS is better to solve this problem. Especially since clearing the fifth div is NOT the same as adding a new div to do the clearing.

Comment: Mike is correct. The CSS approach doesn't work well.
My layout has 20 items, 5 columns for each row with total of 4 rows. With "5n+5" the fifth element of grid dropped to second row, and the last item fallen down to the fifth row.